# How to sample two paths of Brownian motion with parameter sigma=1, mu=-1 by Python?

Tags: python, math, probability

I try to sample two paths with the same parameter which are `sigma=1`, `mu=-1` and the initial position is `2`. But I do not know how to sample two paths at the same time. Here is my code for single path of Brownian motion by Python:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(5)
fig = plt.figure()
T = 1
N = 501 # Number of points, number of subintervals = N-1
dt = T/(N-1) # Time step
t = np.linspace(0,T,N)

# Preallocate arrays for efficiency:
dX = [0]*N
X = [0]*N

# Initialization:
dX[0] = np.sqrt(dt)*(1*np.random.randn(0,1)-1) # Eq. (3)
X[0] = 2

for i in range(1,N):
    dX[i] = np.sqrt(dt)*(1*np.random.randn()) # Eq. (3)
    X[i] = X[i-1] + dX[i] # Eq. (4)

plt.plot(t, X)
plt.xlabel('Time $t$', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Random Variable $X(t)$', fontsize=14)
plt.title('1D Brownian Path', fontsize=14)
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([0,T])
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Uncomment to save the image
#fig.savefig('brownian_1d.png', dpi=600)
```

Comment: Repeat the same code twice?

Comment: @Julien Yes, just want to sample two random paths.

Comment: I understand, and you can do it by repeating your current code twice. Or check my answer below...

Comment: Please fix the indentation in the code. The titles on Stack Overflow do not support (La)TeX.

Comment: @Julien How to repeat the same code twice? I repeat the same code but there just appears the same figure twice but not two paths in one picture.

Comment: Only set the seed once at the start. Then define e.g. `Y` just like you define `X`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a concise way to do it:

```
mu = -1
sigma = 1
X0 = 2
K = 2 # number of paths
dX = np.sqrt(T/(N-1)) * (sigma*np.random.randn(N, K)+mu)
X = np.cumsum(dX, axis=0) + X0
```

Comment: But I want to sample two paths which are not standard normal distribution but $N(-1, 1)$. How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: It's better to have the `K` axis in the front and call `cumsum` over the last axis.

Comment: It's your opinion. Pizza taste better without pineapple... Also will force you to transpose back to plot.

Comment: No, it's performance improvement due to how strides in arrays work, and also convention of stacked quantities all over the scipy ecosystem.